# Laravel.log file not updating log

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I installed `laravel 5.6` and pasted everything on server Digital Ocean. Now `Laravel.Log` file not updating anything. Is there any step should I take to solved this?

`.env` file:

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:S2IOFJ8ruj9fUV5qhOWs7+A48DrIM1bIA9yZ83HbRfQ=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    APP_URL=http://localhost

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=mysql
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=*****

    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: are you getting error/notice/warning ?

Comment: this is my live www.yourtradelog.com noting is error just `white page` @C2486

Comment: try to change in developer mode and enable all errors, and then comment here ?

Comment: in `.env` file `APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: how to change `developer` mode? @C2486 sorry for late reply i was taking launch.

Comment: What is your webserver ? check site root .... You should change it to your `public` folder of Laravel project

Comment: yes everything fine. Digital Ocean `Ubuntu server`, connection with `Nginx` @C2486 i have checked `nginx log `

Comment: Is your username is `root`, did you check all credentials are right ?

Comment: yes it `root`. I have set `777` permission to `bootstrap` and `storage` folder and also `log.php ` @C2486

Comment: Try to add a custom log in your main controller. ( index function ) `Log::info("test");`

Comment: how you set document folder to your domain name ? first try with simple `test.html` to check your are at right path ?

Comment: yes, test working fine http://yourtradelog.com/test.html please this url.@C2486

Comment: Which is the main controller? @ArashHatami

Comment: Where you return your main view ... Put a custom log before returning view

Comment: This is fresh laravel 5.6 therefore, main view is `welcome page` right? it is in route. @ArashHatami

Comment: Yes ... @KinnariPrajapati

Comment: There is not any chat ... start one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173670/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-arash-hatami).

Comment: I have started here also @ArashHatami https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173670/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-arash-hatami

Comment: Hello @ArashHatami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom log in your main controller. Or return a normal string instead of view.

```
Log::info("test");
return "test";
```

If nothing changed, there is another problems.

1. Web Server
2. PHP fpm
3. Any OS problem

Correct configurations for a Laravel project :

**Apache**

```
<VirtualHost **IP**:80>
    ServerName yourtradelog.com
    ServerAlias www.yourtradelog.com
    ServerAdmin info@yourtradelog.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/yourtradelog/public
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled user
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup user user
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup user user
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/home/user/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name yourtradelog.com;
    root "/home/user/public_html/yourtradelog/public";
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel.log error;
    sendfile off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```